# Reduce the space between scrolling links

Tags: css

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
    #container {width:300px; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:nowrap;}
    img {border:0;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt=""></a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I reduce the space between the links to 1px?

Many thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the whitespace between them. Put all of them on one line, otherwise you will get a space between them.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I'd prefer to control the space with CSS.

Comment: No can do. It's the content that's causing the space. That said, you might get away with setting `font-size: 1px`.

Comment: Weird: `font-size:1px;` works, but `font-size:5px;` doesn't increase the space. It doesn't seem to be a reliable way to control the space.

Answer (score 1):

This should hopefully work:

```
* {padding:0;margin:0;}
div#container {overflow:auto;}
img {float:left;margin-right:1px;border:0;}
```

Comment: Strange @RainLover - worked for me when I tested it in dreamweaver.

http://i50.photobucket.com/albums/f349/billymoat/demo.jpg

Do you have a a test URL you can share with us?

Is the code you've posted the actual code you're working with or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

Hey add to img properties `vertical-align:top;` in your css  as like this

```
img {
    border: 0 none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/nZKv8/

Comment: I can still see the space between the images.